# Entity Framework ApplicationUser child entities return null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

We have an ApplicationUser class which inherits from IdentityUser. An ApplicationUser can have many devices.

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

A Device is defined as

```
    public partial class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
}
```

The one-to-many relationship is set in

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Device>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceID);

            entity.Property(e => e.DeviceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Devices).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        public virtual DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

The following code correctly returns the user

```
var membershipUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

I know membershipUser has 6 devices in the Devices table, however the Devices property is null.

The following also returns null for this users devices

```
var deviceList = membershipUser.Devices.ToList();
```

How do I wire up Devices so they are correctly returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loading doesn't work on `EF7`. But You can use `Include` in your request.

Comment: Thank you @aqua from mars. For others who might stumble on this issue here is the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797) to the issue tracker for lazy loading.

Comment: This is a totally correct answer, however not entirely helpful in the case of `ApplicationUser`, which is typically loaded with a call to `_userManager.FindByFoo(foo)` and does not support the `.Include` extension method like a normal EF query would.  A more complete answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875569/ef7-identity-not-loading-user-extended-properties