# Custom UserStore in Asp .Net 5 beta 7

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a custom `UserStore` in `Asp .Net 5 beta 7` based on the idea presented [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26759735/649497).

Here is the code for my custom user store:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }


    public async override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        var user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        this.Context.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Subject).Load();
        return user;
    }
}
```

I am encountering two issues with this code.

1. No method *FindByIdAsync* to override in the base class
2. Inside *FindByIdAsync*, the method *Reference* is not found

I am also not sure how I would go about configuring the custom user store once I get it to compile.

UPDATE:

The first issue I have solved by changing the definition of the FindByIdAsync override to the following:

```
public async override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken))
```

The second issue is still a problem. How do I specify in `EF7` that I wish to explicitly load the reference property `Subject` of my `ApplicationUser` entity? In `EF6` the following is defined in the namespace System.Data.EntityFramework.Infrastructure:

```
public DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty> Reference<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationProperty) where TProperty : class;
```

Where is this extension method defined in `EF7`? Or is there a new method for explicitly loading references?

Comment: Wait for a week (more...), they're going to change all structures again, it will be Identity v.5 and will let you configure your authentication creating only 20 classes and overriding 80 methods... (ah, and don't forget interfaces, it has more than a thousand). And the best, this time it will be well documented.

Answer (score 0):

That question you are referring to is very old and a lot has changed in Identity since then.

I can tell you I have implemented UserStore in my project without using entity framework and my class is declared like this:

```
public sealed class UserStore<TUser> :
    IUserStore<TUser>,
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
    IUserEmailStore<TUser>,
    IUserLoginStore<TUser>,
    IUserRoleStore<TUser>,
    IUserClaimStore<TUser>,
    IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser>,
    IUserLockoutStore<TUser>,
    IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>
   where TUser : SiteUser
{
.. implementation
}
```

where SiteUser is my own custom class

you may also find [this question helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795792/how-to-use-asp-net-identity-3-0-without-entity-framework/31813863#31813863) as it shows how I plugged in my custom userstore in DI

looks like you do want to use EF but the principals of how to declare and plug in a custom userstore should be the same with or without a dependency on EF

Comment: Thanks, Joe for the information. The question that you linked will I think help for configuring the user store once it compiles. Yes, I am using Entity Framework. I am essentially trying to solve the same problem in the question that I linked to; namely that the user object being returned by FindByIdAsync does not have the reference properties loaded.